# TypeScript typing of url params in React Router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom, router, typing

I try to typing url params, but get error "type {} is missing the following properties from type RouteComponentsProps<MatchParam,StaticContextn unkwon>: history, location, match
How correctly typing url params in TS.

```
<Route exact path="/page/:id">
  <DetailsPage  /> ----> error here 
</Route>
```

```
interface MatchParams {
  id:string
}

const DetailsPage = (props: RouteComponentProps<MatchParams>) => {
 const {id} = props.match.params
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you render your component as below

```
<Route exact path="/page/:id">
  <DetailsPage  /> ----> error here 
</Route>
```

the DetailsPage doesn't get the route props provided by react router.

so you need to render your Route as

```
<Route exact path="/page/:id" component={DetailsPage} />
```

or

```
<Route exact path="/page/:id" render={(props) =>  <DetailsPage {...props} />} />
```

Comment: yeah, its works, but it's style like old version of react router, in new V5 you can pass component as a child. There is a hook useParams that works fine, but i wonder if i can do that without hook, just to understand properly what's going on

Comment: This is the source code of the Route component from react-router-dom, If you see L62 - https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L62 . when your children is not a function , you are just rendering the children and not passing any additional props to it .